# Split an array into chunks

Tags: arrays, perl, splice

My objective: To take a file of 5 quiz questions and break the file down into those 5 questions. The code I have makes sense to me (how i see it in the comments), but perl is telling me that I am using an uninitialized variable at the line "@question1 = join ...." Can anyone shed some light on this? I thought that I was initializing the values before the while. Thanks in advance.

```
my $filename = "test.txt";                    #open file
open my $test, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open file '$filename' $!\n";

my @lines = ();                     #attempt to initialize variables
my @question1 = ();

while (<$test>) {   #while file is open

    push (@lines, $_);      #push each line into the array "lines"
    my @lines = split /\n/, @lines;  #split the array at the newlines

    @question1 = join ("\n", sort (@lines[0..5]));  
    #make @question1 = to lines 0-5 of the array

        print @question1, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you post your question file? It sounds like there may be an easier way to do what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the format of your input file, it's more difficult to advise you on how to split it into five chunks, but here are some general pointers that you can use.

### Reading a file in, one line at a time

If your input file has one question per line, you can read it in using a similar method to what you has posted in your script.

Contents of test.txt:

```
Q1. Why colour is red?
Q2. How many is too many?
Q3. What about me?
```

Script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; # to visualise data structures

my $filename = "test.txt";
open my $test, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open file '$filename' $!\n";

my @lines;
# go through text.txt one line at a time
while (<$test>) {
    chomp;                # remove the line ending
    push @lines, $_;      # push each line into the array "lines"
}
# view the data structure    
print Dumper \@lines;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
  'Q1. Why colour is red?',
  'Q2. How many is too many?',
  'Q3. What about me?'
];
```

A shorthand way of doing this is:

```
open my $test, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open file '$filename' $!\n";

my @lines = <$test>;      # read all lines into @lines
chomp @lines;             # remove all the line endings

print Dumper \@lines;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
  'Q1. Why colour is red?',
  'Q2. How many is too many?',
  'Q3. What about me?'
];
```

Now you've got all your questions in the array `@lines`; question 1 is `$lines[0]`, question 2 is `$lines[1]`, question 3 is `$lines[2]`, and so on.

### Reading a file in in chunks

How about if your input file has a question followed by three possible answers (as in your previous question)? Example input file format:

```
1.) question one text
 a.) solution a
 b.) solution b
 c.) solution c

2.) question two text
 a.) solution 2a
 b.) solution 2b
 c.) solution 2c

3.) question three text
 a.) solution 3a
 b.) solution 3b
 c.) solution 3c
```

You can set the [input record separator, `$/`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR), to a custom value to split up your file into what you consider to be a record. By default, `$/` considers a line to be a record. If you set `$/` to `""`, it will read in the file in paragraph mode, meaning that any set of two or more consecutive new lines (i.e. `\n\n`, `\n\n\n`, etc.) will delimit a record. To parse a file in the format above, you would do:

```
my $filename = "test.txt";
my @lines;
{
    local $/ = "";
    open my $test, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open file '$filename' $!\n";
    @lines = <$test>;
}
print Dumper \@lines;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
  '1.) question one text
 a.) solution a
 b.) solution b
 c.) solution c

',
  '2.) question two text
 a.) solution 2a
 b.) solution 2b
 c.) solution 2c

',
  '3.) question three text
 a.) solution 3a
 b.) solution 3b
 c.) solution 3c
'
];
```

Giving the input record separator a different value is useful if we want to do any operations on the input. For example, let's split up each question in a set of lines:

```
my $filename = "test.txt";
my @lines;
my @questions;
{
    local $/ = "";
    open my $test, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open file '$filename' $!\n";
    while (<$>) {
        # split up the input into lines
        my @temp = split "\n", $_;

        # find lines starting with a digit and a full stop ( /^\d\./ ) from @temp
        # push them on to the array @questions
        push @questions, grep /^\d+\./, @temp;

        # push a reference to @temp on to @lines (@lines is now an array of arrays)
        push @lines, [ @temp ];
    }
}
print Dumper \@questions;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
  '1.) question one text',
  '2.) question two text',
  '3.) question three text'
];
```

View the structure of `@lines`:

```
print Dumper \@lines;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
  [
    '1.) question one text',
    ' a.) solution a',
    ' b.) solution b',
    ' c.) solution c'
  ],
  [
    '2.) question two text',
    ' a.) solution 2a',
    ' b.) solution 2b',
    ' c.) solution 2c'
  ],
  [
    '3.) question three text',
    ' a.) solution 3a',
    ' b.) solution 3b',
    ' c.) solution 3c'
  ]
];
```

### Reading in a file in as a single string

Another common way to handle file contents is to read the file in as one long string. To do that, you need to set the input record separator to undefined:

Contents of test.txt:

```
Q1. Why colour is red?
Q2. How many is too many?
Q3. What about me?
```

Script:

```
my $filename = "test.txt";
my $lines;
{
    local $/;
    open my $test, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open file '$filename' $!\n";
    $lines = <$test>;
}
print Dumper($lines);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 'Q1. Why colour is red?
Q2. How many is too many?
Q3. What about me?
';
```

You should be able to find at least one method amongst these that will suit your input and your purposes. If you can't, you'll need to post your input file and what you want your output to look like.

[More information on file operations in perlfaq5](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfaq5)

[More information on Perl's special variables in perlvar](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar)

Answer (score 1):

I think the biggest and best lesson you can learn from this is that any comments you add *don't* make your code do what they say. Comments that are just hopes and wishes are far worse than no comments at all.

You should be commenting your code *only* when it is so extremely complicated that it is unclear what you have written. In this case you seem to be reading an input file and printing the same thing. That doesn't need commenting, especially with wishful thinking.

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program
- Then this. It's fine, but you're emptying two empty arrays and have a bizarre comment. Why is it an "attempt"?

  ```
  my @lines = ();                     #attempt to initialize variables
  my @question1 = ();
  ```
- And this is a lie

  ```
  while (<$test>) {   #while file is open
  ```

  You're looping while `<$test>` is a *true* value. Reading from a file handle *never* closes the file
- This could be okay

  ```
  push (@lines, $_);      #push each line into the array "lines"
  ```
- Except there's now this

  ```
  my @lines = split /\n/, @lines;  #split the array at the newlines
  ```

  which declares a *brand new and separate* array `@lines`, and passes the first and second elements of the *old* `@lines` as the second and third parameters to `split`. Bear in mind that, up to now, you had only a *single line of the file* in the *old* `@lines`, so you are splitting *one line* on the newline at the end
- Now there's this

  ```
  @question1 = join ("\n", sort (@lines[0..5]));
  ```

  so you're rejoining the *single line* that you just split and stuffing it into a one-element array `@question1` to contain just that split and rejoined string
- Then

  ```
  print @question1, "\n";
  ```

  which prints that one-element array followed by a newline.

After that is the end of the `while` loop, so you just go and do the same thing again, one line at a time.

You're pretty much copying the input to the output, one line at a time, via splitting each line into a single-element arrays and copying it into another one-element array,